# Jsoup: Table with class name

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I recently began using the Jsoup library and have had some issues accessing classes and printing the parsed code. I want to print out the team name ("NYE") and the amount of wins (14), and I have tried multiple ways to execute this problem, including using getElementsByClass, getElementsByTag, select, and a few others and have yet to have any luck producing an output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed u-verticalPadding--x-small ScrollArea-content">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th/>
                <th class="Standings-header-team"/>
                <th class="Standings-header" title="Division">DIV</th>
                <th class="Standings-header" title="Matches Played">MP</th>
                <th class="Standings-header" title="Match Wins">W</th>
                <th class="Standings-header" title="Match Losses">L</th>
                <th class="Standings-header" title="Maps Won, Lost, Tied">Map W-L-T</th>
                <th class="Standings-header" title="Map Differential">DIFF</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>1</b>
                </td>
                <td class="Standings-details-team">
                    <div class="IconLabel">
                        <span class="IconLabel-item">
                            <img src="https://bnetcmsus-a.akamaihd.net/cms/page_media/3PBR8VEYM8SH1517250447953.svg" alt="New York Excelsior" class="Icon">
                            </span>
                            <span class="IconLabel-item hidden-xs">
                                <div>New York Excelsior</div>
                            </span>
                            <span class="IconLabel-item hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl" title="New York Excelsior">
                                <div>NYE</div>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="Standings-details-division">ATL</td>
                    <td class="Standings-details">16</td>
                    <td class="Standings-details">14</td>
                    <td class="Standings-details">2</td>
                    <td class="Standings-details">51-15-2</td>
                    <td class="Standings-details is-positive">+36</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Lets start by describing how do You know which data you want do extract? How do you recognize/find it?

Comment: @Pshemo I know that I need the team name and the the records, which I will be importing that output into an excel table and then use that table in my java web application. I see that the span classes like IconLabel-Item store information like team name, but I have yet to to scrape the attributes of that span to get the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be able to parse the data you are looking for. I added comments to the code to help you understand what each step is doing.

```
// Use CSS selectors to select the table header elements that correspond
// to the table data rows we want to select (i.e. team name and wins)
Element teamNameElement = doc.select("th.Standings-header-team").first();
Element winsElement = doc.select("th[title='Match Wins']").first();

// Get the index within the table header that the elements are at 
// (will be used to find the appropriate table data in the table row).
int teamNameIndex = teamNameElement.elementSiblingIndex();
int winsIndex = winsElement.elementSiblingIndex();

// Select the first table row. This contains the data we want to grab.  
Element tableRow = doc.select("tbody > tr").first();

// Use the indexes we found earlier to get the team name and wins <td> elements
Element teamNameData = tableRow.getElementsByIndexEquals(teamNameIndex).first();
Element winsData = tableRow.getElementsByIndexEquals(winsIndex).first();

// There are multiple span elements in the team name <td> so grab the one
// at index 1 which contains the name.  
Element name = teamNameData.select("span").get(1);

System.out.println("Team Name: " + name.text());
System.out.println("Wins: " + winsData.text());
```

Output:

```
Team Name: New York Excelsior
Wins: 14
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging it looks like there is a script that loads the table which is my guess

```
<section class="Section  Section--no-sides Section--thin-top">
  <div class="container">
   <div id="standings"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is what jsoup gives you for that section which you are trying to pull the table from

Check out this https://api.overwatchleague.com/standings?expand=team.content&locale=en_US if parsed correctly it will give you all the information in the table and more